# Import react native AAR to native andorid - inaccessible classes error

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, aar

I try to ad library that write in RN.
I build aar and add to my demo native android app.
That was lot of problems that occurs in process , but I resolved.

I get error that i understand what it's mean but I don't success to resolve this. the eror is :

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void androidx.core.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in ...**

I read answers to resolve this issue. but they don't work.

What i understand when u I open this file. NetInfoModule that use in react use old libraries. but gradle build NetInfoModule with androidx . the result is this error :".. is inaccessible to class.."

Do anyone know how to solve inaccessible classes?